# fsi (FSharp interactive) quiet mode

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

How can I limit the output to the F# Interactive console to my own output?

In my current setup the fsi writes lots of information (on types and content of the data structures) as it runs through the script.
I have tried the [quiet mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172.aspx) without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can set [ShowDeclarationValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842573.aspx), [ShowProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842577.aspx), and [ShowIEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842569.aspx) to false.

You may still see types, but not content (which is generally the bulk of the output).

```
#if INTERACTIVE
fsi.ShowDeclarationValues <- false
fsi.ShowProperties <- false
fsi.ShowIEnumerable <- false
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Another unconventional method might be the following:

- fire your FSI with [`--quiet` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172.aspx)
- instead of `printf` use [`eprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340259.aspx) for your own output, the effect would be exactly what you asked for

in the script

```
eprintfn "Testing: %n" 123
```

in FSI window

```
Testing: 123
```

Any other, but **real error messages** output simply will not appear in the FSI window, including all evaluation results; at the same time all conveniences of `printf` are still available to you, including familiar formatting.

**UPDATE:** I [posted](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/quieting-fsi-output/) a further enhancement allowing use of unchanged output code for both normal and "quiet" modes of FSI output.